# Regex: capture only if the entire line contains a pattern

Tags: regex

New to regex..

I'm trying to find a way to capture all characters up until the first underscore but only for lines that don't contain "-NEW" anywhere in the line.

So, in the example below, the first line would result in no group 1 match since the line contains "-NEW". 
The remaining lines would all have the first part up to and excluding the first underscore captured as a group 1 match. 
Is this possible with regex?

skipme_garbage-NEW_nothing
**takeme**_garbage_some-otherstuff
**takemetoo**_some_more_garbage
**alsotakeme**_0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for what I understand you want. You can see a [demo I made on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KD1iYV/2).

```
^([^_]+)(?!.*new)
```

- `^` match beginning of line
- `([^_]+)` match any character that's not an underscore and store in group
- `(?!.*new)` negative forward look ahead. Match fails if `.*new` occurs anywhere else in the line.

Comment: @Rob, You should include your initial attempt in the question. This is likely why you're getting down-votes.